# CMake - using external libraries as APR

Tags: build, cmake, shared-libraries

I am quite new to this CMake.

I need to use APR from Apache 2 and I have a problem with this build system. The Apache 2 web server is installed under the **C:\Apache24** folder, the APR related include files are located under **C:\Apache24\include** and the libraries under the **C:\Apache24\lib** folder.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(json C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 90)
include_directories(
    C:\Apache24\include
)
link_directories(
    C:\Apache24\lib
)
target_link_libraries(
    json apr-1.lib
)
add_executable(larak larak.h larak.c main.c)
```

By build I get this error:

```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "larak" which is not built by this project.
```

I've already read a lot of similar posts but most all of them are for Linux/Unix systems, not for Windows and not for APR/Apache.

Comment: The first parameter to `target_link_libraries` should be the name of your executable (`larak`). And call to `target_link_libraries` should come **after** `add_executable` call. See duplicate question and its answers for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command specifies libraries to link for a **specific** target. This target name must be provided as the *first* argument to the command, and must already be defined earlier in your CMake file. Since you only have one target, `larak`, defined in your CMake file, you probably want to do something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(json C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 90)
include_directories(
    C:/Apache24/include
)
link_directories(
    C:/Apache24/lib
)

add_executable(larak larak.h larak.c main.c)

target_link_libraries(larak PRIVATE
    apr-1.lib
)
```

Careful, CMake will probably complain about the backslash usage (`\`) you have. You should convert these to forward slashes.

Note, you may instead specify the full path to the library in the `target_link_libraries()` command, to avoid the use of the `link_directories()` command.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(json C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 90)
include_directories(
    C:/Apache24/include
) 
add_executable(larak larak.h larak.c main.c)

target_link_libraries(larak PRIVATE
    C:/Apache24/lib/apr-1.lib
)
```